# Does the SparkPost webhook configuration accept :port in the URL?

Tags: sparkpost

I'm trying to configure a webhook on the SparkPost web UI.

The URL for the webhook has a `:port` part, like

```
http://myserver.company.com:5000/webhook/accept
```

I can post JSON to this URL just fine, using Postman or curl, but the SparkPost UI at https://app.sparkpost.com/account/webhooks does not accept it. Looks like it's going to port 80, despite what the URL says.

Could this be true?  Or do I have some other problem?

Comment: I use port 8080 and it works for me. I would look for an alternate problem. You could query the webhook endpoint and see if there is something helpful in the status.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the firewall/router, not with SparkPost.